# Нажимаем на кнопку до появления другой

Tags: javascript

Я хочу сделать автокликер на сайт, что бы он останавливался при появлении этой кнопки(код ниже) на странице, изначально кнопка скрыта под стилем `Display:none;`, можне взять какой либо текст из блока, не обязательно эту кнопку

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="confirmButton" data-tid="0">Check Status</button>
```

Я сделал автокликер так, по таймеру он ищет на странице текст, если его нет он выполняет клик по кноке, а если текст был найден таймер обнуляется, но у меня не получается, потому что значения условие находит из исходного кода, такое не устраивает т.к. если в исходном коде есть кнопка это не значит что она без стиля display:none. Вроде объяснил понятнее.

```
    var b = $('b'),
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (b.filter(':contains("текст")').length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      console.log('Приехали');
      return false;
    }
    document.getElementById("showConfirmButton").click();
  }, 2000);

button.on('click', function() {
  console.log('Клик');
});
```

но я в чем то ошибаюсь и у меня не получается... помогите исправить проблему

Кнопка по которой кликаем `<button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" style="width:100%" onclick="showConfirm()" id="showConfirmButton">Withdraw Items</button>`

Comment: Как именно появляется новая кнопка?

Comment: мы не знаем как заполяется массив `button`, что происходит внутри `click()` и что такое `timer`

Comment: @Igor, `click` - это триггер для события клика; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click .

Comment: timer = setInterval(function() {

Comment: Добавьте это в код!

Comment: @SloGS - я задал три вопроса, Вы ответили на один. У кого из нас трудности?

Comment: На странице есть скрытые элементы то есть они скрыты как 
`display: none;` когда они появляются как `display: block;` нужно прекратить клики, или же можно взять какой то определенный текст из скрытого блока, заместо кнопки, мне просто нужен автокликер до появления элемента на экране

Comment: ТС, все новые подробности как можно **детальнее** перенесите в вопрос.

Comment: Вроде как исправил вопрос, прочтите вроде детальнее

Comment: @SloGS мы не знаем, как заполяется массив `button` и что происходит внутри `click()`

Comment: Никогда не используйте код, когда пытаетесь объяснить, что вам нужно сделать. Сначала простым русским языком напишите, что вам нужно сделать, а потом выкладывайте код того, что у вас получилось. И тогда вам ответят быстро и качественно. А вопросы в которых идёт постоянная отсылка в авторский код, очень сложны для понимания и остаются без ответа.

Comment: Исправил все что вы просили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может помочь [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

```js
// Для примера клика
let value = 0;
function up() {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\(\d+\)/, `(${++value})`);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  // Установим начальные значения
  let button = document.querySelector('#confirmButton'),
    someButton = document.querySelector('#someButton');

  someButton.addEventListener('click', up);

  setTimeout(() => {
    button.style.display = 'inline-block';
  }, 1000);




  // Теперь ловим момент появления!
  // Ставим автокликер
  let timer = setInterval(() => {
    someButton.click();
  }, 300);

  // Отслеживаем изменения кнопки
  let observer;
  (observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    mutations.forEach(mutation => {
      if(getComputedStyle(button).display !== 'none'){
        observer.disconnect();
        // Если изменение привело к отображению кнопки, убираем таймер
        clearInterval(timer);
        // И делаем что хотели
        console.log('Приехали');
      }
    });
  })).observe(button, {
    attributes: true,
    childList: true,
    characterData: true
  });
});
```

```css
#confirmButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type='button' id='someButton' value='Count (0)' />
<button class="btn btn-success" id="confirmButton" data-tid="0">Check Status</button>
```

Comment: Вы очень помогли, спасибо большое