# Как остановить setInterval получив определенный ответ с сервера на определенное действие?

Tags: javascript

`setInterval` запущен, в интервале кликает на кнопку отправляет определенный запрос кликами, в ответ на клик мы получаем ответы на запросы, как обнулить `setInterval` получив определенный ответ?

Допустим при получении такого ответа -

```
success: false 
error: Attempting mobile confirmation: success
```

Посылаем запрос так -

```
let confirmButton = document.querySelector('#confirmButton');
let success = setInterval(() => {
                confirmButton.click();
}, 3000);
```

Кнопка запроса -

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="confirmButton" data-tid="0">Check Status</button>
```

Comment: почему в интервале? так и делайте: если ответ такой какой надо - останавливайте интервал

Comment: я просто не знаю как работать с запросами и ответами от сервера, хотел спросить у вас пример

Comment: стоит добавить код как посылается запрос

Comment: А JS код-то где?

Comment: _setInterval запущен, в интервале кликает на кнопку отправляет определенный запрос кликами,_ - вот этот код нужен

Comment: Добавил JS код.

Comment: и разметку для _#confirmButton_, ну и код добавления обработчика _onclick_ для него

Comment: Добавил кнопку в пост

Comment: _и код добавления обработчика onclick для него_

Answer (score 0):

Может стоит самому делать, а не по кусочкам заставить [других сделать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/523827/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9)?

```js
// Помогает установить контроль над исполнением
let flag = true;

function clickHandler(){
  /*fetch('/some').then(json => json.json().then(result => {
    // Тут проверяем какой ответ и решаем - нужно ли остановить таймер
    // Если нужно остановить цикл, ставим флаг (flag) в false
  }));*/
  
  // Для теста
  let rand = Math.random();
  
  console.info(`Click, rand ${rand}, ${rand > 0.5 ? 'change' : 'continue'}`);
  
  rand > 0.5 ? flag = false : null; // 50/50
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  // После загрузки DOM, ищем кнопку и вешаем обработчик
  let confirmButton = document.querySelector('#confirmButton');
  confirmButton.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
  
  // Запускаем цикл
  loop(confirmButton);
});

function loop(btn){
  if(flag){ // Если флаг позволяет, ставим таймер на клик в будущем и производим его сейчас
    setTimeout(() => loop(btn), 3000);
    btn.click();
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="confirmButton" data-tid="0">Check Status</button>
```

Comment: Делаю я то сам, перед тем как спрашивать я ищу в интернете путевую информацию, а если не нахожу ничего, то приходится спрашивать, а автокликер мне нужен с целым рядом действий, поэтому и приходится постоянно приходить на данный сайт и спрашивать у знающих людей, мне весь код даже не надо писать за меня, а просто подсказать в каком направлении двигаться и в каких функциях рыться

Comment: @SloGS, но ведь очевидно - запускаем, проверяем, если надо, останавливаем. Хотя может это я - Гений? :)

Comment: Скорее всего это вы гений, я знаю что нужно запускать, проверять, если подошло остановить, знаю как запустить, знаю как остановить, а как сравнить ответ на запрос с нужным значением для условия, я незнаю(((((

Comment: @SloGS, ? `if(response === 'something') stopTimer()` или как-то так.

Comment: Как строится условие я знаю, но у меня вопрос, как взять данные с ответа для условия?

Comment: @SloGS, зависит от способа запроса. В закомментированном примере это `result` - `JSON`-объект ответа. А как Вы уже у себя сделали запрос - это Ваш вопрос :)